# Neo4J, cypher and wildcards not working

Tags: regex, lucene, neo4j, cypher, wildcard

I have read the various answers on SO and also the help pages for neo4j. However, I can't get my wildcard match to work. For example, if I put in the cypher query

```
MATCH (author:Author )-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WHERE article.id =~ 'Art10526689' RETURN author, article.date
```

I get the correct answer. however, If I put in the query

```
MATCH (author:Author )-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WHERE article.id =~ "Art1052668*" RETURN author, article.date
```

I do not get anything returned. I have used '"' because it seems that the lucene might be sensitive, and the '=~' because it was suggested it was better than simply doing `(article:Article {id:'Art1052668*'})`, though that doesn't work either.

As usual, any help will be deeply appreciated!

Regards, Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richard, you are close to an answer.  It think what is happening is you an misconstruing wild carding with the regular expression syntax supported by Neo4j.  In you query the `8*` actually means match `8` and 0..infinitely more 8s. If you are looking to just replace the `9` in the article id with a single character then you would use the `.` character.  If you would like `0..infinite` characters after the `8` then you would use `Art1052668.*`.  You can add case insensitivity too with `(?i)`, see example below...

```
MATCH (author:Author )-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WHERE article.id =~ "(?i)Art1052668.*" 
RETURN author, article.date
```

Comment: D'UH! Of course, it is regexp, I was thinking straight wildcards! Brillliant, thanks